# Chained questions closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

So a recent closed question got me thinking. When we flag something as duplicate, should we point to the 'parent' question that was not closed as duplicate?

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/91515/should-i-put-weed-related-job-on-my-resume) was recently closed as a duplicate (fair enough) but it links to a further three questions that were all closed as duplicate before getting to the main 'parent' question of this. Is it considered best practice to do this or would it be more appropriate to link to the final question directly?

Comment: We should point to the question (closed or not) that has the best answer.

Comment: It's particularly interesting in this case because while it may be duplicate of the question on unorthodox content, it's not a duplicate of the 'parent' question about adult entertainment.

Comment: related: [Marking question as duplicate of duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250202/839601) (at MSO)

Comment: Hold my controversial job, I'm going in!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of discussions on this on main meta and also on some other site-specific metas that you can have a look at. I believe the SOP is to close it as a duplicate of the question that most suits what the new question was asking about. Often you'll have a single "core" question, for example about how to define working time in the US, and then a closed question that asked "Does activity X count as work time?". A new question "My boss wants me to do Y but won't consider it time worked" should then likely be closed as a duplicate of the latter question.

As of a [recent update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291824/gold-tag-badge-holders-and-moderators-can-now-edit-duplicate-links) gold-tag badge owners and moderators can adjust the duplicate question list. We can add or remove questions and reorder them. If you feel like a particular question is missing from the list, you can flag a post accordingly. But I'd suggest doing so sparingly, pointing to a single link in the chain is usually enough in my experience.